# ReactDOM dynamically rendering components from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want my `RenderDOM` to render one component for each object found in an array. I'm building the render with JSX, and my code is as follows:

```
ReactDOM.render((
            <div className="container container-collapsed">
                <Actions Units={aUnits} />
                <div className="units-wrapper">
                    {
                        aUnits.forEach(u=> {
                            return <Unit unit={u} />
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        ), document.getElementById("root"));
```

I expeted the output to be like this:

```
<div class="container container-collapsed">
    <div class="actions-panel_true"></div>
    <div class="units-wrapper">
        <div class="unit1"></div>
        <div class="unit2"></div>
        <div class="unit3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And instead I'm getting:

```
<div class="container container-collapsed">
    <div class="actions-panel_true"></div>
    <div class="units-wrapper"><div>
</div>
```

I know that my foreach is working, I debbuged it. But it is not building one JSX per units as I expcted. How to I make this foreach loop return one  component for each object in my array, back to the JSX i'm trying to render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
ReactDOM.render((
   <div className="container container-collapsed">
      <Actions Units={aUnits} />
      <div className="units-wrapper">
         {aUnits.map(unit => {
            return (
               <Unit key={u.key} unit={u} />
            );
         })}
       </div>
   </div>
), document.getElementById("root"));
```

A couple notes:

```
<Unit={u} />
```

is not a valid syntax. You are suppose to assign `u` to a property of the `Unit` component, not the component itself. Also, when rendering array of items, you should supply a `key` property to each item as to help React differentiate between them. You'll find more information about why this is important [In the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: Thank you! <Unit={u}/> was a typo in my question. I'll update it. On the actual code I'm doing <Unit unit={u}/> as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You need `.map` instead of `.forEach` to return an array so that React can render it effectively.

Also returning from the callback inside `.forEach` has no use since `.forEach` doesn't return an array. It returns `undefined`.

`.forEach` is useful when you want to change the contents of existing array without returning a new one. In **React**, JSX requires an array as a result of `.map` operation.

Also more valid points covered by @zhulien